# Android ListView Multiple Row Give Views values in getView method

Tags: android

In getView method i try to set textview text.I have two different type of object. If i use "position" in parameter it gives "IndexOutOfBoundsException" error normally. How can i set text each of them appropriately?

```
Context context;
ArrayList<OfficialKanal> officialKanals;
ArrayList<NormalKanal> normalKanals;
ArrayList<Object> kanallar = new ArrayList();
int OFFICIAL_KANAL = 0;
int NORMAL_KANAL= 1;
LayoutInflater lala;
public KanalAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<OfficialKanal> officiallar , ArrayList<NormalKanal> normaller){
    this.context = context;
    officialKanals = officiallar;
    normalKanals = normaller;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < officiallar.size() ; i++){
        kanallar.add(officiallar.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < normaller.size() ; i++){
        kanallar.add(normaller.get(i));
    }
    Log.i("tago" , "tagtag");
    lala = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return kanallar.size();
}

public Object getItem(int i) {
    return kanallar.get(i);
}

public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = getItem(position);
    if(item instanceof NormalKanal){
        return NORMAL_KANAL;
    }else if (item instanceof OfficialKanal){
        return OFFICIAL_KANAL;
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    KanalHolder holder = null;
    int pozisyon = 0;
    Object currentKanal = getItem(position);
    if(convertView==null) {
        holder = new KanalHolder();
        if (currentKanal instanceof OfficialKanal) {
            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.officialkanal, null);
            holder.image2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            holder.buton2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button7);
            holder.buton3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
            Log.i("tago", "tagtagatagtagtagatg");
        }
        if (currentKanal instanceof NormalKanal) {
            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.normalkanal, null);
            holder.image1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            holder.buton1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
            Log.i("tago", "tagtagtag");
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (KanalHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        if(currentKanal instanceof OfficialKanal){
            holder.tv3.setText(officialKanals.get(position).getKanaladi());
        }
        if(currentKanal instanceof NormalKanal){
            holder.tv1.setText(normalKanals.get(position).getKanaladi());
        }
    return convertView;
}


static class KanalHolder{
    public ImageView image1,image2;
    public TextView tv1 , tv2,tv3,tv4;
    public Button buton1,buton2,buton3;
}
```

Comment: What about creating a new model (let's say `Kanals`) which contain a boolean flag, to indicate if its official or nromal? Then your adapter handle only one model, and you can load the desired xml depending on this flag.

Answer (score 0):

issue is `getCount` getView will call according to size of `kanallar`

```
public int getCount() {
   return kanallar.size();
}
```

but you getting value from `officialKanals` and `normalKanals` in `getView`

try like for experiment

```
if(currentKanal instanceof OfficialKanal){
        holder.tv3.setText(kanallar.get(position).getKanaladi());
    }
    if(currentKanal instanceof NormalKanal){
        holder.tv1.setText(kanallar.get(position).getKanaladi());
    }
```

Comment: Yes but if i change it listview doesn't be formed truly.